# Style does not apply

Tags: html, css

```
<tr>
   <td class="main" align="left">

    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="navbar">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
</tr>

#menu {
    border: 1px solid #D9D4D4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 100px 0px 0px 20px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Why menu style does not apply to div? If I explicity paste this style in *element* in Firefox when it works.

Comment: Are you using twitter-bootstrap? If so bootstrap's styling may be overriding your CSS.

Comment: there is no twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Does it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/287gfz23/ ?

Comment: @Andy Is this your HTML directly? If so, you need to put your CSS in a `<style></style>` tag.

Comment: @MarkCidade yes, it works there...

Comment: @Marcelo no, it is not direct code, all styles are in css file

Comment: @Andy Well, as has been said, there is nothing wrong with your posted code. The next steps are to make sure your CSS file is loading and that no other rules are overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

I see this working correctly, please see the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ksuk4fr/

Maybe try styling the li using `#menu li` if you want to style menu elements

If you are going for the #menu itself use the inspector in firefox or chrome to see what's overriding it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to over-qualify, try

```
div#menu { ... }
```